# Python default keyword parameters persisting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code

```
def func(para = []):
    para.append(1)
    return para
    
print(func())
print(func())
```

the output is

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

The function somehow reuses `para`, I realize pointers are used for classes, lists, dicts, etc but here the `para` should be redefined as it is not being passed when `func` is called.

I don't remember it being like this, either way, is there a way to make it so `para` resets to a empty list when `func` is executed?

Comment: Lists are mutable, so if you alter it the changes will stick. Some IDEs will even give you a warning. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try: 
def func(para = None):
    if para is None:
        para = []
    para.append(1)
    return para
    
print(func())
print(func())

Answer (score -1):

The reason that it's happening is because a list is mutable, to fix it use a immutable value like a string as a default parameter.